# Postgres String to Date EXAMPLE 10Apr77 to 10/04/1977

Tags: postgresql, date

Good afternoon all,

I'm fairly new to PostgreSQL, so apologies in advance if my question is below the average.

I'm receiving  some data in a csv flay file format and is nicely being insert in to a staging table for me to preview the data.  On of the things i have an problem with is the data field is store as a string value. For example,  10Apr96 - 01Jan85

I've wrote the below query to see if could break the string up and concat back together in a date format.

Is there an easier way to achieve what I'm doing ?

```
select 
concat(cast(substring(datetext,1,2) as varchar(2)),'/',case 
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Jan' then '01'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Feb' then '02'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Mar' then '03'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Apr' then '04'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'May' then '05'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Jun' then '06'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Jul' then '07'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Aug' then '08'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Sep' then '09'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Oct' then '10'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Nov' then '11'
when cast(substring(datetext,3,3) as varchar(3)) = 'Dec' then '12'
end,'/',cast(substring(datetext,6,2) as varchar(2))) as dt
from tbl_loading_horses_tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the code you're using and some of the data it applies to. In future it's also good to mention your PostgreSQL version, but thanks for making the effort to explain yourself clearly, +1.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [the `to_date()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html), which takes a format string of how to interpret the input and returns a `date` value which is what you should be storing in your DB.

```
SELECT to_date('10Apr96', 'DDMonYY');
  to_date   
------------
 1996-04-10
(1 row)
```

To convert that back to a string in a different format when retrieving for display, use the `to_char()` function documented on the same page.

Comment: I've added a bit more explanation and a link to the documentation, but this is definitely the right approach.