# How do I cast a date to a string so this query will run?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run the following query in postgresql:

```
select * from movies where release_date = current_date;
```

It responds with the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = date
LINE 1: select * from movies where release_date = current_date;
                                                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

It seems like I need to cast the date returned by the current_date function into a string so that way the comparison will work. How do I do that?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067372/postgres-string-to-date-example-10apr77-to-10-04-1977 it'll show you how to cast a string (your release_date) into a date.  But, why isn't your release_date stored as a date in your database?

Comment: What's the column type for `release_date`?

Comment: Why are you storing a date in a text column? And if you can't fix your schema, what format is `release_date` in?

Comment: Yes my date column in the database should be a date column instead of a string. This is just a quick test app I'm using to learn with otherwise I would have been more thorough in my database creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from movies where release_date::date = current_date;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5d66f/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `release_date` column is able to be cast to a date, you'd be best off with:

```
select * from movies where cast(release_date as date) = current_date;
```

The `CAST` function is part of the [SQL-92 standard](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.programmer.doc/doc/s0005330.sql-92.cast.function.html) and will keep your query portable across multiple platforms.